# Can do I use TFPT 2008 with VS2005/TFS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs-power-tools

We have TFS 2008 but use Visual Studio 2005.  I would like to use some of the features from tfpt.exe 2008 but when I try to install tfpt, it will not install the commandline tool.

My guess is that it won't install it because I don't have Visual Studio 2008.  Can anyone confirm this?  Does anyone know how to get around this?

Since we use TFS 2008 I don't see any reason why I shouldn't be able to use TFPT 2008.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio 2005 with TFS 2008.

But you cannot access client functionality that is specific to TFS 2008 with Visual Studio 2005.

TFPT is a client side tool so it requires VS 2008.

TFPT = Team Foundation Power Tools

Comment: I was thinking TFPT was self-contained but it does make sense that it uses the VS2008 components.  I think I can solve this by downloading Team Explorer 2008.  Its working so far for me.  thanks.